# How to make elevation to project shadow on the top view, within same LinearLayout

Tags: android

I was able to use `elevation`, make top red color view (`FrameLayout`), to project shadow on bottom yellow color view (`RecyclerView`), within same `LinearLayout`. It looks like

[image]

The code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="#ff0000"

        android:padding="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_frame_layout"
        android:elevation="18dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backup_now_button"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:text="BACKUP NOW" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"

        android:background="#ffff00"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

However, if the red view is move to bottom, the shadow is no longer projected.

[image]

The code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"

        android:background="#ffff00"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="#ff0000"

        android:padding="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_frame_layout"
        android:elevation="18dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backup_now_button"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:text="BACKUP NOW" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

May I know why it is so? Is it possible to overcome this?

Comment: can you try wrapping your linear layout in cardview

Comment: No. No cardview.

Comment: the yellow layout is background view, so a yellow background is a full screen, take a view above red layout within yellow view

Comment: @CheokYanCheng as you can see, you set elevation on the (yellow) frame, and elevation is shadowed only towards the bottom and the sides of the view ... so, as expected, if you move it to the bottom, the elevation is still shadowed but you will not see it, because you don't have any space on screen to show it

Comment: @kubersingh Yellow item is recyclerview.

Comment: @Alessio Any way to make the bottom red view project shadow on top yellow view?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng if you want to project the shadow on top there are ways, but I would strongly discourage them (even if you won't like this answer). First, because you'll go against Material Design, and second because you'll fight against the system.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng now I can't test myself, but try to add a very big top padding for the red frame view, and a very strong elevation ... I think you should see a very small shadow then, on top of it ... this is just to say that there's shadow there, as projected by the system, but it's basically null with your elevation. Alternatively you could add a drawable to mock the shadow, but once more I wouldn't.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng : do you want to use it for devices below android 5.0?

Answer (score 0):

I have the check yet but you can try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:background="#ff0000"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_frame_layout"
    android:elevation="18dp"
    android:background="#ffff00"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:overScrollMode="always"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"

    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:padding="18dp"
    android:id="@+id/button_frame_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
        android:id="@+id/backup_now_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="BACKUP NOW" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```